# Mapping of the function return type based on input type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

### Problem Description

I have a function called `createProduct` which accepts a `Spec` as an input and produces a `Product` as an output.

The `Spec` uses discriminating unions (`type: 'a' | 'b'`). Types `ProductA` and `ProductB` are incompatible, as in don't have overlap in their field definitions.

Is there a way to type `createProduct` so that it ensures that when `SpecA` is used, it will produce `ProductA`, and when `SpecB` is used, it will produce `ProductB`?
Basically, I am looking for some kind of type mapping.
Pseudocode: `createProduct<Spec = SpecA|SpecB>(spec: Spec): <SpecA => ProductA | SpecB => ProductB>`

Of course, this will not work if I pass a spec variable that is typed as a `Spec`. But I think, it should be possible to achieve that if I pass a literal as an argument such as `{ type: 'a' }`;

### Code

```
type Spec = SpecA | SpecB;
interface SpecA {
  type: 'a';
}
interface SpecB {
  type: 'b';
}

type Product = ProductA | ProductB;
interface ProductA {
  properyA: 'unique property of A';
}
interface ProductB {
  properyB: 'unique property of B';
}

export function createProduct(spec: Spec): Product {
  if (spec.type === 'a') return { properyA: 'unique property of A' };
  else if (spec.type === 'b') return { properyB: 'unique property of B' };
  else return spec; // spec: never
}

export function consumeProductCreator(): void {
  const product = createProduct({ type: 'a' });
  // The type of `product` is just `Product` but I want it to be inferred as `ProductA`
  // by adjusting the signature of `createProduct` function.
}
```

Comment: Tried [overloads](https://tsplay.dev/N5AYZN) yet? Alternatively, a [map](https://tsplay.dev/ND8jxN).

Comment: @pink the map option still uses the overloads, right?

Comment: Well, it's just 1 "external" overload to hide the underlying implementation signature, so you don't get any pesky errors when trying to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you add two overloads:

```
export function createProduct(spec: SpecA): ProductA;
export function createProduct(spec: SpecB): ProductB;
export function createProduct(spec: Spec): Product {
  if (spec.type === 'a') return { properyA: 'unique property of A' };
  else if (spec.type === 'b') return { properyB: 'unique property of B' };
  else return spec; // spec: never
}
```

Now it's:

```
export function consumeProductCreator(): void {
  const product = createProduct({ type: 'a' });
  //    ^? const product: ProductA
}
```

For more details, see the documentation on defining function overloads (which is really only a signature overloading, as you cannot overload the implementations like you would in other languages like Java - but you don't need to in this case) here:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: If you call `createProduct(product)` where product is of type `Spec`, this raises an error since no overload matches the call.

Comment: @pink No overload matches Spec implicitly, but the overloads mach all possible kinds of Spec as defined in the question. So passing this `const spec: Spec = { type: 'a' };` doesn't give an error for me (TypeScript 5.0.4)

Comment: Interesting. That works but `createProduct(... as Product)` doesn't. Nevertheless, it still returns the wrong type: https://tsplay.dev/NdvX0W (passing a `Spec` should return `Product`, right?)

Comment: Nevermind. I see what's going on here. TypeScript is retaining the fact that `spec` is really a `SpecA`. See https://tsplay.dev/N73DBN This is why you should use `declare` when testing type definitions. What I mean by "retaining" is that when you have a `const` and you widen the value's type, the *real* type of the value is still being used under the hood.